# What is the equivalent working Rust code example for this WAT (WebAssembly Text) example?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-wasm, wasmtime

The below [WAT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format), adapted from a couple of Wasmtime examples, runs absolutely fine embedded in my application but what I thought was the equivalent Rust code fails with:

```
Running `target\debug\hello_world.exe`
Error: expected 5 imports, found 1
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\hello_world.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

Here's the working WAT:

```
(module
  (import "host" "greet" (func $greet (param i32 i32)))
  (func (export "run")
    i32.const 4  ;; ptr
    i32.const 22 ;; len
    call $greet)
  (memory (export "memory") 1)
  (data (i32.const 4) "Calling back from WAT!")
)
```

And the failing Rust:

```
use std::ffi::CString;

#[link(wasm_import_module = "host")]
extern "C" {
    fn greet(ptr: i32, len: i32);
}

static GREETING: &str = "Calling back from Rust!";

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn run() {
    let greeting = CString::new(GREETING).expect("contains null byte");
    let ptr = greeting.as_ptr();
    std::mem::forget(ptr);

    unsafe {
        greet(ptr as i32, GREETING.len() as i32);
    }
}
```

My minimal example app that embeds the WASM modules:

```
use std::str;

use anyhow::Result;
use wasmtime::{Caller, Engine, Extern, Func, Instance, Module, Store};

struct MyState {
    name: String,
    count: usize,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let engine = Engine::default();
    let code = include_bytes!("../hello.wat");
    let module = Module::new(&engine, code)?;

    let mut store = Store::new(
        &engine,
        MyState {
            name: "Hello, junglie85!".to_string(),
            count: 0,
        },
    );

    let greet_func = Func::wrap(
        &mut store,
        |mut caller: Caller<'_, MyState>, ptr: i32, len: i32| {
            let mem = match caller.get_export("memory") {
                Some(Extern::Memory(mem)) => mem,
                _ => anyhow::bail!("failed to find host memory"),
            };
            let data = mem
                .data(&caller)
                .get(ptr as u32 as usize..)
                .and_then(|arr| arr.get(..len as u32 as usize));
            let string = match data {
                Some(data) => match str::from_utf8(data) {
                    Ok(s) => s,
                    Err(_) => anyhow::bail!("invalid utf-8"),
                },
                None => anyhow::bail!("pointer/length out of bounds"),
            };

            println!("> {} {}", caller.data().name, string);
            caller.data_mut().count += 1;

            Ok(())
        },
    );

    let imports = [greet_func.into()];
    let instance = Instance::new(&mut store, &module, &imports)?;
    let run = instance.get_typed_func::<(), ()>(&mut store, "run")?;

    println!("# Global count = {}", store.data().count);
    run.call(&mut store, ())?;
    println!("# Global count = {}", store.data().count);

    Ok(())
}
```

What is the Rust equivalent of the WAT example?

Comment: Casting a pointer to an `i32` is unsound, better use `usize` instead. Your code also won’t compile (missing lifetime specifier). You don’t need to use `CStr` and create a static either. Forgetting a pointer is useless.

Comment: @Miiao usize also sux for casting a pointer, thus yeah way better than i32 XD

Comment: @stargateur, `usize` is exactly what a pointer is at run-time (at compile time, casting a pointer to any integer is UB)

Comment: @Miiao no it's not, that why pointer is a pointer and that usize is an usize. I warn about this for years, and then as predicted shit happen, https://tratt.net/laurie/blog/2022/making_rust_a_better_fit_for_cheri_and_other_platforms.html, https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-usize-is-not-size-t/15369